# Trying to convert a byte stream into an image in Python

Tags: python, sockets, udp, pi

Let me start by saying I am relatively new to python so please don't shoot me because I don't know the answer to solving my problem.

Using a Raspberry Pi (4B), I am trying to send an image file from one transceiver to another transceiver.  For the sake of simplicity in testing I have both transceivers connected to the 1 Pi.  The transceivers I am testing with a PiicoDev 915MHz transceivers.  Now I could use UDP and Sockets (and yes I have that code working) but I don't want to as that defeats the purpose of using transceivers which are an ideal technology when there is no wifi / internet or 4G/5G services.

**Sender Code Description**
I believe my sender code is fine, it starts by sending a string based 'START' string with a number, the number being the number of packets that it will take to break the input image into.  Once the START packet and number of packets is sent, the method then sends the image data as a byte stream.  See sender code below.

**Receiver code Description**
The receiver code detects the START string and number of packets (count) and then proceeds to receiving the byte data for the number of packets. Each time a data (byte stream) packet are received it adds the contents to an aggregated byte stream variable.  Once all the packets are received the program is supposed to display the contents of the byte stream as an image (which in theory should be the same as the sender image).  However, this is where the problem lays (around line 81 of receiver code). See receiver code below.

**Error received**
Upon starting the receiver script, then initiating the send script, data appears to be transmitted and I can see the send count go to the end (around 42 packets) and the receiver is also receiving and shows a count of 42 packets.  However once all the packets are received I get the following error:

```
All packet data received successfully!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pimaster/Desktop/PiicoDev/Tranceiver-Image-Examples/Transceiver-Image-Example-5/RECEIVE-Image-Transceiver-NonUDP-Method Template v5 TEST.py", line 101, in <module>
    getimagedata()
  File "/home/pimaster/Desktop/PiicoDev/Tranceiver-Image-Examples/Transceiver-Image-Example-5/RECEIVE-Image-Transceiver-NonUDP-Method Template v5 TEST.py", line 81, in getimagedata
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(received_data))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2958, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0xf6d27bb8>
```

I am at a loss as to how to solve the error and convert the byte stream to an image.  I have looked everywhere to try and solve the error but to no avail...

**SENDER CODE**
This is my sender code (note the error is generated in the receiver code):

```
# The purpose of this code is to send an image file across a PiicoDev Transceiver

# Include statements for the transceiver
from PiicoDev_Transceiver import PiicoDev_Transceiver
from PiicoDev_Unified import sleep_ms

# Include/imports for image stuff
from PIL import Image
import PIL

#setup the PiicoDev sensors / output devices
transmitter = PiicoDev_Transceiver(id=[0,0,0,0])


# Open and read the JPEG image
image_path = "/home/pimaster/Desktop/PiicoDev/Tranceiver-Image-Examples/Transceiver-Image-Example-5/Test-Image.jpg"
with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
    image_data = image_file.read()

my_new_image = b''


# Define the packet size for splitting the image data
PACKET_SIZE = 1024


# Create a function to split data into packets and send them
def send_data(data):

    packet_count = (len(data) + PACKET_SIZE - 1) // PACKET_SIZE
    print("Packet count is " + str(packet_count))
    my_packet_sent_counter = 1
    
    # Send the initial packet START with a packet count - as a string
    transmitter.send(f"START{packet_count}")
    sleep_ms(500)
    
    #Transceiver - Send packet of image data, but send in BYTE format
    for i in range(0, len(data), PACKET_SIZE):
        packet = data[i : i + PACKET_SIZE]
        transmitter.send(packet)
        print('Sending packet number ' + str(my_packet_sent_counter) + ' , Byte position ' + str(i))
        my_packet_sent_counter += 1
        sleep_ms(50)
        

    # Don't send an END packet as there is no point.
    #transmitter.send(f"END")
    #print('Sending END packet')


try:
    send_data(image_data)
    print("Image packets sent successfully!")
    

except Exception as e:
    print("Error sending image:", e)
```

**RECEIVER CODE**

```
# This is my receiver code.  The intention is to receive packets of image data from a
# transceiver and then show the image once all the packets have been received.


# Include/imports statements for the transceiver
from PiicoDev_Transceiver import PiicoDev_Transceiver
from PiicoDev_Unified import sleep_ms

# Include/imports for image stuff
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import UnidentifiedImageError

import io
import re

#setup the PiicoDev sensors / output devices
receiver = PiicoDev_Transceiver(id=[1,0,0,0])


# Define our global vars
received_data = b''
data = b''
expected_packet_count = 0
current_packet_count = 0

# Not sure if I need to set a path for PIL but will add it in just in case it is needed
path = Path("/home/pimaster/Desktop/PiicoDev/Tranceiver-Image-Examples/Transceiver-Image-Example-5/").rglob("*.jpg")

# Listen for incoming connections and data
def lookforstart():
    startnotfound = True
    global expected_packet_count
    
    while True:
        if receiver.receive():
            message = receiver.message
            
            if ('START' in message):
                numberofpackets = int(re.search(r'\d+', message).group())
                expected_packet_count = numberofpackets
                print("Expected packet count is " + str(expected_packet_count))
                startnotfound = False
                if startnotfound == False:
                    break
            

def getimagedata():
    global expected_packet_count
    global current_packet_count
    global received_data
    global data
      
    while True:
        
        if receiver.receive():
            
            data = receiver.message
            encoded_data = data.encode()
            
            # increment the packet received count
            current_packet_count += 1
            
            print("Received packet " + str(current_packet_count) + " of " + str(expected_packet_count))
            print("Packet received is " + (str(type(data))))
            print("Aggregated data of all packets so far is " + (str(type(received_data))))
            print("Data packet received is of type " + (str(type(encoded_data))))
            print(" ")
                           
            # add the data packet to the aggregated received_data
            b''.join([received_data,encoded_data])
            
            
            
            # Jump into the IF statement if all the packets have been received
            if current_packet_count == int(expected_packet_count):
                    
                print("All packet data received successfully!")    
                
                # Load the data stream into BytesIO object - 
                image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(received_data))
                
                # save the image to a file
                image.save('image_from_data_stream.png')
                
                
                #path = Path("/home/pimaster/Desktop/PiicoDev/Tranceiver-Image-Examples/Transceiver-Image-Example-4").rglob("*.jpeg")
                break
                
            
try:
    # Look for the initial START packet and get the intended packet count
    lookforstart()
    
    # Now get the data packets and display the image
    getimagedata()
    
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Terminating...")
```

SNAP-SHOT of Receiver Code Output
I thought it may be useful just to show a snapshot of the output from the receiver code when both the sender and receiver code are running, up to the point of the error...

```
Received packet 37 of 42
Packet received is <class 'str'>
Aggregated data of all packets so far is <class 'bytes'>
Data packet received is of type <class 'bytes'>
 
Received packet 38 of 42
Packet received is <class 'str'>
Aggregated data of all packets so far is <class 'bytes'>
Data packet received is of type <class 'bytes'>
 
Received packet 39 of 42
Packet received is <class 'str'>
Aggregated data of all packets so far is <class 'bytes'>
Data packet received is of type <class 'bytes'>
 
Received packet 40 of 42
Packet received is <class 'str'>
Aggregated data of all packets so far is <class 'bytes'>
Data packet received is of type <class 'bytes'>
 
Received packet 41 of 42
Packet received is <class 'str'>
Aggregated data of all packets so far is <class 'bytes'>
Data packet received is of type <class 'bytes'>
 
Received packet 42 of 42
Packet received is <class 'str'>
Aggregated data of all packets so far is <class 'bytes'>
Data packet received is of type <class 'bytes'>
 
All packet data received successfully!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pimaster/Desktop/PiicoDev/Tranceiver-Image-Examples/Transceiver-Image-Example-5/RECEIVE-Image-Transceiver-NonUDP-Method Template v5 TEST.py", line 101, in <module>
    getimagedata()
  File "/home/pimaster/Desktop/PiicoDev/Tranceiver-Image-Examples/Transceiver-Image-Example-5/RECEIVE-Image-Transceiver-NonUDP-Method Template v5 TEST.py", line 81, in getimagedata
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(received_data))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2958, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0xf6d27bb8>
```

Anyhow if anyone is able to help me overcome the error and be able to display and/or save the image from the bytestream data i'd be extremely grateful.

Thanking you all.  James.

Comment: `b''.join([received_data,encoded_data])` creates a new object and does not update `received_data`. Change it to `received_data += encoded_data`.